# TcpClient stream write doesn't apply until stream/connection is closed

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

I'm trying to make a simple TCP program. I can get the client to connect to the server, but when my client calls stream.Write, the server does not read the sent data until the client closes the connection.

In addition to this, when my client attempts to read the server's response, the client throws an IOException. ("The connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.")

Server code:

```
listener.Start();
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
//Wait for message
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ns.CopyTo(ms);//server will hang here until connection is closed, then receive correct data
```

Client code:

```
client.Connect(endpt);
client.GetStream().Write(encodedMessage, 0, encodedMessage.Length);
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ns.CopyTo(ms); //client crashes here
```

Comment: You're running the server first ?

Comment: @VasilutLucian Yep

Answer (score 2):

No, the server reads the data just fine. It's just that the stream doesn't end until you close the connection - the `CopyTo` method has no way to know that you want it to stop reading at some point. Remember, TCP doesn't send *messages*, it maintains a bi-directional stream of bytes. If you need messages, you need to build a messaging protocol on top of TCP.

The same thing happens on the client side, so you basically have a deadlock there - the client can't close the connection until it reads the whole stream, and the server can't close the connection until it reads the whole stream (indeed, it doesn't even accept any *new* connections, since you're doing all of this on one thread). But again, a TCP stream only ends when the connection is shutdown. So both are going to wait for each other forever.

I certainly don't get a crash, though. Are you trying to connect two clients to the same server at the same time? This will not work with your present code, and will cause a timeout like yours. The problem is that the connection is still waiting in the server's queue, and you don't call `AcceptTcpClient` until the previous connections are closed (again, the `CopyTo` deadlock).

Networking is quite hard. I'd certainly recommend you to use a well-tested, well-designed communication framework instead of rolling your own TCP-based protocol. Something like WCF or Lidgren will likely help quite a bit. If you really want to make your own TCP-based communication, you'll need to go through quite a bit of learning - I'd really like to recommend a good resource, but I haven't found any for C#/.NET so far. I've started a few samples on [Networking](https://github.com/Luaancz/Networking), but that's far from production-ready code, and rather incomplete. It will show you the basic ideas of how an asynchronous TCP server is built in C#, as well as how to implement a simple HTTP-style or message-style TCP-based protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    //Server Part
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server started...");

        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, 1234);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                HandleClient(client);
            })).Start();
        }
    }

  private void HandleClient(TcpClient client)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII) { AutoFlush = true };
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII);

        string inputLine = reader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The client with name " + " " + inputLine + " is conected");

    }


//Client Part
 public void InitClient()
  {
        client = new TcpClient("localhost", 1234);
        stream = client.GetStream();
        writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true };
        reader = new StreamReader(stream);
  }

  public void SendMessage(string userName)
  {
     writer.WriteLine(userName);
  }


 //And here are the type of the variable that are used:
    TcpClient client;
    NetworkStream stream;
    StreamWriter writer;
    StreamReader reader;
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using AcceptSocket rather than AcceptTcpClient on the server, and using the Socket Receive function.

The client also now reads into an array rather than using the CopyTo function.

New server code:

```
listener.Start();
Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
byte[] b = new byte[999];
socket.Receive(b);
```

New client code:

```
client.Connect(endpt);
client.GetStream().Write(encodedMessage, 0,encodedMessage.Length);
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
byte[] bb = new byte[999];
ns.Read(bb, 0, 999);
```